# Unused JS file in Ext JS application

Tags: performance, extjs4

How can I know which js files are unused in my extjs4 application, I want to delete them from my application because it cosumes about 10s before the first page appears, and the sdk folder size is more than 9 Mo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually use Sencha SDK to combine all your (and core ExtJs) .js files into two big files one with ExtJs, second with your app. I think full ExtJs file for version 4.0.7 takes about 1.5M - which is not big deal. The rest depend of how big and complex your application.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how I can use the Sencha SDK in the developpement cycle because as far as I know the sencha sdk is used to create minified **production-ready** builds.

Comment: Yes. Isn't that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm still developping the application, I mean I'm still using extjs-debug file,and if I generate a minified production-ready file I can't debug the application or am I wrong ?!

Comment: Correct. But then why do you care about loading time?

Comment: Because it takes a lot of time, for example when I update the code I have to refresh the browser and this refresh action takes a lot of time before loading js files from the server.

Comment: You can't have it both ways... You either debug the stuff - and then you load files individually, or you load them fast but then you don't debug. You can try develop using local web server, it should be enough fast